# Add more csv files to a datagridview in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, csv

This is the button which I press in order the csv-s to be imported:

```
private void btnOpen_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        using (var fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog())
        {
            DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();

            if (result == DialogResult.OK && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fbd.SelectedPath))
            {
                //  string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath);
                string[] csvFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\CSV", "*.csv");
                foreach (string filePath1 in csvFiles)
                {
                    BindData(filePath1);
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the method that is called for each csv. The problem is that it makes the datagridview each time the last csv is imported. I want a way that adds all the records not only my last imported csv:

```
private void BindData(string filePath)
    {
     
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      
        using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(filePath))
        {
            // configure your parser to your needs
            parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
            parser.Delimiters = new string[] { ";" };
            parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = false; // no messy code if your data comes with quotes: ...;"text value";"another";...

            // read the first line with your headers
            string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();

            // add the desired headers with the desired data type
            dt.Columns.Add(fields[0], typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add(fields[1], typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add(fields[6], typeof(float));
            dt.Columns.Add(fields[7], typeof(float));
            dt.Columns.Add(fields[8], typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add(fields[9], typeof(string));
        
            // read the rest of the lines from your file
            while (!parser.EndOfData)
            {
                // all fields from one line
                string[] line = parser.ReadFields();

                // create a new row 
                DataRow row = dt.NewRow();

                // put data values; cast if needed - this example uses string type columns
                row[0] = line[0];
                row[1] = line[1];
                row[2] = line[6];
                row[3] = line[7];
                row[4] = line[8];
                row[5] = line[9];

                // add the newly created and filled row
                dt.Rows.Add(row);
                
            }
        }
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        // asign to DGV


    }
```

Comment: Do ALL the CSV files have the same schema/column structure? If so, then define the `DataTable` and its columns in the `btnOpen_Click_1` code “before” the `foreach` loop. Then pass the same (pre-defined) `DataTable` to the `BindData` method. Currently the `DataTable` is “defined” in the `BindData` method… `DataTable dt = new DataTable();` … therefore, each time the method is called a new table is created.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
```

So it says:

```
DataTable dt = (this.dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable) ?? new DataTable();
```

So that you either reuse your existing data source or make a new one if it is not set